# Custom UIVIew layoutSubviews causes an error when setting a transform (AutoLayout asks me to call super method even though I already am)

Tags: ios, uiview, autolayout, layoutsubviews

I've got a strange issue where I'm trying to override `-layoutSubviews` to create a different layout in landscape. My method works fine in portrait, but when I set a transform on one of my subviews in landscape, I get this error:

```
 *** Assertion failure in -[LSSlideNotesView layoutSublayersOfLayer:], /SourceCache/UIKit/UIKit-2380.17/UIView.m:5776
 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Auto Layout still required after executing -layoutSubviews. LSSlideNotesView's implementation of -layoutSubviews needs to call super.'
```

My method is as follows:

```
-(void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];
    bool horz = UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape([UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation);
    if (horz) {
        CGRect contentFrame = self.bounds;
        contentFrame.size.width -= (notesHeight + 40);
        if (contentFrame.size.width < 0) {
            contentFrame.size.width = 0;
            notesHeight = self.bounds.size.width - 40;
        }
        slideCarouselView.frame = contentFrame;
        remotePointerView.frame = contentFrame;

        // ***** This is the offending line *****
        notesLabel.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-M_PI_2);
        // **************************************
        notesLabel.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, contentFrame.size.height, 40);
        notesLabel.center = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMaxX(contentFrame) + 20, contentFrame.size.height / 2);

        CGRect notesRect = self.bounds;
        notesRect.origin.x = notesRect.size.width - notesHeight;
        notesRect.size.width = notesHeight;
        notesTextView.frame = notesRect;
        labelCopyFail.frame = CGRectMake(contentFrame.size.width / 2 - 65, contentFrame.size.height * 3 / 4 - 20, 130, 30);
    } else {
        CGRect contentFrame = self.bounds;
        contentFrame.size.height -= (notesHeight + 40 + keyboardHeight);
        if (contentFrame.size.height < 0) {
            contentFrame.size.height = 0;
            notesHeight = self.bounds.size.height - keyboardHeight - 40;
        }
        slideCarouselView.frame = contentFrame;
        remotePointerView.frame = contentFrame;

        notesLabel.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
        notesLabel.frame = CGRectMake(CGRectGetMinX(contentFrame), CGRectGetMaxY(contentFrame), contentFrame.size.width, 40);

        CGRect notesRect = self.bounds;
        notesRect.origin.y = notesRect.size.height - notesHeight - keyboardHeight;
        notesRect.size.height = notesHeight;
        notesTextView.frame = notesRect;
        labelCopyFail.frame = CGRectMake(contentFrame.size.width / 2 - 65, contentFrame.size.height * 3 / 4 - 20, 130, 30);
    }
}
```

If I comment that line out, I don't get the error. Does anybody know why this would happen? Am I missing something? I've done almost this exact transform elsewhere in my app and it works just fine. I cannot for the life of me figure out what is going on here. I'm willing to try pretty much anything.

Comment: Is LSSlideNotesView a subclass of UIScrollView?

Comment: No, it's a subclass of UIView.

Answer (score 1):

Well, this isn't really a full answer, but I wanted to document my fix since it does reveal a little more about the problem, and could possibly help someone out.

So it turns out that the issue was somehow related to the interface builder (I think). I had this subclass of UIVIew described above being instantiated by the storyboard (by changing the class type of the root view in the view controller). I was also linking the subviews in the storyboard to `IBOutlets` in the view. Apparently that does some funny stuff, perhaps overriding or changing some of the default layout mechanisms.

Once I pulled the view completely out of interface builder and instantiated and added everything manually in code, it worked fine.